# Configure mockoon with a seed to always return the same random data between requests

Tags: rest, mocking, mockoon

Although I am using faker to generate random data I would like the responses of a given endpoint to be the same on every request.

I noticed the general settings have an input text for setting a `seed` but does nothing regarding what I am aiming at.

Answer (score 0):

Faker.js seeding is not always generating the same information.
Instead, it will always generate the same sequence. I'm not sure it's documented on Faker.js' website, but I added this to [Mockoon's documentation](https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/templating/fakerjs-helpers/#set-faker-js-locale-and-seed).
If you want the answer to always be the same you can either:

- use the inline body with "static" data (without templating), something like:

  ```
  {
    "username": "john"
  }
  ```
- use the [data buckets](https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/data-buckets/overview/) feature as they are only generated once when the server starts.